# Does the function $f(x)=x$, $x\in (0,1)$ have a maximum and minimum value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My book says that since we cannot determine the value of x when it is just less than 1 and just greater than 0, hence the function does not have a maxima or minima. But the fact confuses me because although we cannot determine those values, they still exist. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Here is an intuition why there is no maximum nor minimum value : Suppose you find $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)$ is the maximum. Since $(0,1)$ is an open set, for any x, you can find another point right next to it that is greater. Therefore the maximum was not one and therefore there exist none.

Comment: I think the source of your confusion is how you use the word "value". The *numbers* $0$ and $1$ exist, but they are not *values* of your function. (There is no point $x$ in the interval $0<x<1$ such that function's value $f(x)$ at that point is $0$ or $1$.)

Answer (score 5):

No you can't!  Remember for the maximum to exist the function actually has to assume that value in some point.

You know that $f(x) = x$ on $(0, 1)$ is always less than $1$, for example. So you can say that $\sup_{x \in (0,1)} f(x) = 1$

But that does not mean that the maximum of $f(x)$ is $1$, because $f(x)$ is *never* one, is it?
On the other hand, the maximum cannot be any other number, because for any number $\alpha < 1$ the function $f(x)$ is going to assume a value that is bigger than $\alpha$ (as long as $x$ is very very close to $1$, $f(x)$ can get aribitrarily close to $1$, but never gets there)

Therefore the maximum does not exist. Same thing for the minimum

Answer (score 1):

The number you "want" to be the maximum, $1$, is called the *supremum*. It will satisfy your itch.

Similarly, the *infimum* is $0$, which is analogous to the minimum.

The difference is that the supremum needn't be actually achieved at a point of the domain, whereas the maximum must.

Supremum/infimum are also known as least upper bound/greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

> But the fact confuses me because although we cannot determine those values, they still exist.

No, they don't exist, because they don't exist. It can be shown that there exists no maximum or minimum for the function as defined. Keep in mind what it means for a function to be a minimum or maximum:

- **Maximum:** The maximum $f(x)$ occurs at the point $x$ such that $f(x) \geq x$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.
- **Minimum:** The minimum $f(x)$ occurs at the point $x$ such that $f(x) \leq x$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

The implication here is that $f(x)$ exists for some $x$ for it to be an extreme.

---

Let's suppose $f(x) = x, x \in (0,1)$. Suppose it has a maximum $M$.

From the definition of $f$, then, it is clear $0 < M < 1$.

But consider the midpoint of $M$ and $1$. From the above inequality,

$$\frac{M+1}{2} < \frac{1+1}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{M+1}{2} > \frac{0+1}{2} = \frac12 > 0 \tag 2$$

$$\frac{M+1}{2} > M \iff \frac12 > \frac M 2 \iff 1 > M \tag 3$$

We discuss:

- $(1)$ and $(2)$ establish the midpoint is in the image of $f$
- $(3)$ establishes the midpoint is greater than $M$. This only happens if $M < 1$, which is true from $M$'s definition.

Thus, if $M$ is the maximum, we have $(M+1)/2$ which is greater than $M$ yet also still in the image of $f$. Thus, $M$ is not the maximum, giving us the contradiction that $f$ cannot have a maximum.

An analogous proof follows for the minimum.